# CSS: Font Weight Property Doesn't work on font family, why?

Tags: html, css, fonts

The `<head>` tag in my html file contains this link call:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then I go on to say:

```
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    .textTime {
        font-weight: 700;
    }
</style>
```

Then my body goes on to say this:

```
<div class="textTime">
    from 6am to 6am
</div>
```

It gets rendered like so:

[image: bold font not lato]

However, if I change the `font-weight` property to `font-weight: 400;` instead of `700`, it gets rendered like so:

[image: regular font lato]

So my problem is, the font is getting rendered as Lato, only if the weight is 400, not 700, then it gets rendered as something else.

The way it's doing this is because it's using CSS2, not CSS3, and I can't change this.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does swapping 400 and 700 around like `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700,400" rel="stylesheet"> ` do anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using custom font's you need to add each font type for each weight you are going to use.

The reason you are seeing a broken version of Lato or another font is you either have another font defined for those font weights or you are seeing the browsers render version of Lato which will be based on the Lato 400 and up or down scaled depending and it will look nothing like how you intended.